# Weird box on Mobile preview

Tags: android, iphone, wordpress, mobile, header

I am currently working on a website for [DAVINCI](https://www.davinci.dk/), here I am experiencing problems with the mobile version. Every time I open this website on a Huawei Mate 10 lite, it shows a box next to header similar to the image below!

The box next to header is the problem:
[image]

But if I open it on an iPhone 5S it does not show. 
The image is inserted with slider revolution and the website is made with wordpress.

Comment: A missing image maybe?

Comment: Maybe you can fix it with some css?

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to inspect the box and post your findings here. If it's just a placeholder for a missing image, you could remove the image tag to solve your issue.